# UITableView offset shifts when changing layout constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView that extends slightly over the edge of its superview. In response to a button tap, the I shift the table over by setting a constraint constant. Here's a simple example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var edgeHidden: Bool = true

@IBAction func shiftTableButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shiftTable(edgeHidden)
}

func shiftTable(showEdge: Bool) {
    // Finish any pending layout changes
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Update location of table
    tableViewTrailingConstraint.constant = showEdge ? -50.0 : 0.0

    // Shift the table
    UIView.animate(duration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
        guard let view = self?.view else { return }
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

When I do this the table shifts as expected, but the content offset also changes in the y direction. It looks like the scrollview wants to shift in response to the layout change.

Does anyone know a way around this? I've not had any luck resetting content offsets (I get extremely weird behaviour when I do this), nor has disabling scroll helped.

It also doesn't matter if I don't animate, call `setNeededLayout()` instead of `layoutIfNeeded()` or any other myriad things that other responses suggested.

Comment: You are making your table narrower... Is it possible the row heights are dynamic, and getting taller? Can you edit your question and include before and after images?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't include screenshots, but I'm definitely not making it narrower, just shifting it along the x-axis by changing the trailing constraint. That's the only difference.

Comment: So, it has a fixed-width constraint? Not Leading and Trailing constraints?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have been clear: the table has a fixed width, and no leading constraint. The issue I'm seeing is that the scroll position moves in the y-direction when I change the layout, even though I'm not modifying the table's width or updating its cells.

Comment: Welp, I just made a small sample app to try to demo the problem and... I can't. The table view maintains the correct scroll position when I shift it left and right. There must be something about our app's more complex layout that causes the shift, I'm just not sure what or how to remedy it.

Comment: That'll be tough to debug... Look for anything else that might be getting triggered - data reload? some auto scroll-to-position code? Try changing the trailing constraint by different values... does the vertical shift distance have any relevance to the horizontal distance change? You're calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` first... maybe delay the trailing constraint change until the next layout pass (put it on an async main thread execution)?

Comment: If the width of the table is fixed could you use CGAffineTransform to shift it left and right instead of changing the constraint?